# Word for stealing the voice of the people and misrepresenting it for nefarious purposes

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Say a group of people vote for a leader in an election but the leader then goes on to "*speak for the people*" but actually he's speaking for himself and his cronies. I'd like it to be clearly in a derogatory sense.

> "Mr ..... claimed he was speaking on behalf of the people who voted for him but he was actually **[stealing]** their voice"

What word would best fit here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most suitable word for my context was "Highjack" bringing strong, explicit implication of stealing for their own purposes. The word was contributed in a comment that was subsequently removed. Thanks to that unknown contributor!

Comment: And "thanks" to the anonymous comment deleter.

Comment: Good stuff all around. And excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the term *co-opt*:

> **co-opt** *v. tr.*
>   3. To take or assume for one's own use; appropriate: *co-opted the criticism by embracing it.*

[From TFDO](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/co-opt)

Comment: This is the one I was considering posting but you beat me to it, have a +1.

Comment: +1; I have seen _(mis)appropriate_ used in this context, thanks for _co-opt_.

Comment: I'm not sure co-opt has the negative connotation the OP is looking for.

Comment: It is spoken almost entirely in a pejorative context. In fact, I have never once heard it spoken in a positive light. It's what activists say when some politician who supported their cause gets persuaded by some other force or group to go a different way: they got co-opted.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the title of your question

[Misrepresent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misrepresent)

> to give a false or misleading representation of usually with an intent to deceive or be unfair
>
> to serve badly or improperly as a representative of

For example:

> He claimed he was speaking on behalf of the people who voted for him, but he was mispresenting them when he announced the new policy that would...

Comment: "intent to deceive" isn't enough?

Answer (score 1):

How about *pervert*?

From Google search:

> [pervert](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=pervert+definition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) *verb*:
>   alter (something) from its original course, meaning, or state to a
>   distortion or corruption of what was first intended

Your example:

> Mr ..... claimed he was speaking on behalf of the people who voted for
>   him but he was actually *perverting* their voice

It's hard to find a verb more derogatory than *pervert*, not to mention its other obvious connotations as a noun.

Also, as suggested by @alwayslearning, how about *misappropriate*?

From Dictionary.com:

> [*misappropriate*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/misappropriate?s=t):
>   to put to a wrong use

Your example:

> Mr ..... claimed he was speaking on behalf of the people who voted for
>   him but he was actually *misappropriating* their voice.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'Garble'?
According to M-W

- Garble:
    a :  to so alter or distort as to create a wrong impression or change the meaning
- *garble*  a  story
- the candidate complained that his views had been deliberately *garbled* by his opponent

'Misrepresent' also works though.

Answer (score -1):

[Ventriloquize](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ventriloquize):

> to speak or sound in the manner of a ventriloquist.